# Return a 404 when wrong ttp request type used(e.g. get instead of post) in laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, api, routes, httprequest

I am developing a rest API and sometimes the frontend call an endpoint with the wrong HTTP request type. For example, I have a route (`/users/unassigned`) and the type of the route is "GET". Imagin my frontend call this route with a "POST" request. the following error occurs.
`The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE.`
What I want is that the API response a JSON in these situations and I can handle the exception.
I have used the `Route::fallback` but this method catch every exception of the routes. I need a function that only handles the told problem.

Comment: Use the handler. `App\Exceptions\Handler::class`, In your case even if the response is not JSON? the response code is clear: 404

Comment: You get a 405 error in these cases. That should be enough to handle the response. The content should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much.
I use the following code in my handler.php.

```
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
            switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {

                // not authorized
                case '403':
                    return Response()->json(["error" => "not authorized."],403);
                    break;

                // not found
                case '404':
                    return Response()->json(["error" => "Route not found."],404);
                    break;

                // internal error
                case '500':
                    return Response()->json(["error" => "internal error."],500);
                    break;

                case '405':
                    return Response()->json(["error" => "request type not match."],405);
                    break;

                default:
                    return $this->renderHttpException($exception);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
```

The main point is http code 405 for not allowed methodes. special thanks to @apokryfos.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to handle it with `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
        ], 400);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

This will ouput the error message as json for all exceptions when the request is made by ajax or the request expect json.

You can also add a check for type of exception like this:

```
if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
    // Code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make some adjustment in your exception handler.

in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file's render function

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Route Not Found'], 404);
        }
        else {
            //something else
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

and add `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;` at the top use section.

Answer (score 0):

Check what type of request you are getting in your $request variable, then handle it with condition.

Answer (score 0):

**change in your Handler.php**

*like*

```
protected $dontReport = [
             \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
            \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
            \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
            \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
            \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
            //
];

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
         $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" =>"Unauthorized access", "data" => array());
             return \Response::json($arr);
        }
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
```

Comment: mark as helpful if you get proper your answer. thank you.